# Sorted Order Different with Same Query from MS-Access vs .NET

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I'm porting a legacy Access application to .NET Framework, and need to maintain same data sorting order. Connecting to the same database, the ACCESS application uses an ODBC connection configured as so:

> Microsoft SQL Server Native Client Version 11.00.2100
>
> Data Source Name: Central Host-Set Database
>   Data Source Description:
>   Server: localhost\sqlexpress
>   Use Integrated Security: Yes
>   Database: CentralSQL15
>   Language: (Default)
>   Data Encryption: No
>   Trust Server Certificate: No
>   Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
>   Mirror Server:
>   Translate Character Data: Yes
>   Log Long Running Queries: No
>   Log Driver Statistics: No
>   Use Regional Settings: No
>   Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
>   Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes

In the .NET application I was originally using SqlClient with a connection string to the SQL Server, However I have also tried using OdbcConnection/OdbcCommand/OdbcDataReader, utilizing the exact same ODBC connection as Access. However the sort order is always different between ACCESS and .NET.

For example with the query:

```
SELECT sessionstn3270.sessionid, 
       sessionnames.sessionname, 
       sessionstn3270.sessiontypeid, 
       sessionstn3270.usernameid, 
       sessionnames.host, 
       sessionnames.port, 
       lus.lu, 
       sessionnames.lastmodifiedsn, 
       templates.template, 
       templates.templatetype, 
       sessionnames.sessiontype 
FROM   (sessionnames 
        LEFT JOIN templates 
               ON sessionnames.template = templates.templateid) 
       INNER JOIN (sessionstn3270 
                   LEFT JOIN lus 
                          ON sessionstn3270.sessionid = lus.sessionid) 
               ON sessionnames.sessionnameid = sessionstn3270.sessionnameid 
WHERE  usernameid = 3978 
ORDER  BY templates.templatetype, 
          sessionnames.sessiontype;
```

With SQL Management Studio and .NET app the SessionIDs return in this order:

```
17797
17798
17799
17800
17801
105372
```

With MS Access they return in this order:

```
17801
17800
17999
17998
17797
105372
```

95% of the time I can replicate the same search results by adding `ORDER BY` SessionID DESC, but it's not 100% I've tried different sort orders with different fields, but none works 100% of the time.

Does anybody know what else may affect the returned result order between Access and .NET?

I downloaded ExpressProfiler from http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ and found the following:

When Access sends SQL Query to ACCESS database the following transactions occur:

```
SELECT "dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."SessionID" ,"dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."SessionID","dbo"."SessionNames"."SessionType" ,"dbo"."SessionNames"."SessionNameID","dbo"."Templates"."TemplateType" ,"dbo"."Templates"."TemplateID" FROM "dbo"."SessionsTN3270",\oj "dbo"."SessionNames" LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."Templates" ON ("dbo"."SessionNames"."Template" = "dbo"."Templates"."TemplateID" ) \ WHERE (("dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."UserNameID" = 3978 ) AND ("dbo"."SessionNames"."SessionNameID" = "dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."SessionNameID" ) ) 
go
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int',N'SELECT "SessionID" ,"dbo"."LUs"."LUID" FROM "dbo"."LUs"  WHERE ("SessionID" = @P1)',17797
select @p1
go
exec sp_execute 1,17798
go
exec sp_execute 1,17799
go
exec sp_execute 1,17800
go
exec sp_execute 1,17801
go
exec sp_execute 1,105372
go
SELECT CASE DATABASEPROPERTYEX( DB_NAME(), 'Updateability') WHEN 'READ_ONLY' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
go
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int',N'SELECT "TemplateID","Template","TemplateType"  FROM "dbo"."Templates"  WHERE "TemplateID" = @P1 OR "TemplateID" = @P2 OR "TemplateID" = @P3 OR "TemplateID" = @P4 OR "TemplateID" = @P5 OR "TemplateID" = @P6 OR "TemplateID" = @P7 OR "TemplateID" = @P8 OR "TemplateID" = @P9 OR "TemplateID" = @P10',15,15,15,15,15,33,33,33,33,33
select @p1
go
declare @p1 int
set @p1=2
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int',N'SELECT "SessionNameID","SessionName","Host","Template","SessionType","Port","LastModifiedSN","SSMA_TimeStamp"  FROM "dbo"."SessionNames"  WHERE "SessionNameID" = @P1 OR "SessionNameID" = @P2 OR "SessionNameID" = @P3 OR "SessionNameID" = @P4 OR "SessionNameID" = @P5 OR "SessionNameID" = @P6 OR "SessionNameID" = @P7 OR "SessionNameID" = @P8 OR "SessionNameID" = @P9 OR "SessionNameID" = @P10',204,203,202,201,200,272,272,272,272,272
select @p1
go
declare @p1 int
set @p1=3
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int',N'SELECT "SessionID","SessionTypeID","UserNameID","SessionNameID"  FROM "dbo"."SessionsTN3270"  WHERE "SessionID" = @P1 OR "SessionID" = @P2 OR "SessionID" = @P3 OR "SessionID" = @P4 OR "SessionID" = @P5 OR "SessionID" = @P6 OR "SessionID" = @P7 OR "SessionID" = @P8 OR "SessionID" = @P9 OR "SessionID" = @P10',17801,17800,17799,17798,17797,105372,105372,105372,105372,105372
select @p1
go
declare @p1 int
set @p1=4
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P1 int,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int',N'SELECT "LUID","SessionID","LU"  FROM "dbo"."LUs"  WHERE "LUID" = @P1 OR "LUID" = @P2 OR "LUID" = @P3 OR "LUID" = @P4 OR "LUID" = @P5 OR "LUID" = @P6 OR "LUID" = @P7 OR "LUID" = @P8 OR "LUID" = @P9 OR "LUID" = @P10',18539,18539,18539,18539,18539,18539,18539,18539,18539,18539
select @p1
go
SELECT "SessionTypeID" ,"SessionType"  FROM "dbo"."SessionTypes" WHERE ("HostTypeID" = 200 ) 
go
SELECT "UserNameID" ,"WSUserName" ,"RecordType" ,"Role" ,"SecurityLevel" ,"BuildingCode" ,"FloorLevel" ,"ServerID" ,"Airline" ,"Description" ,"LastModified"  FROM "dbo"."WSUsers" 
go
```

However when SQL Server runs the query, it is much simpler:

```
SELECT SessionsTN3270.SessionID, SessionNames.SessionName, SessionsTN3270.SessionTypeID, SessionsTN3270.UserNameID, SessionNames.Host, SessionNames.Port, LUs.LU, SessionNames.LastModifiedSN, Templates.Template, Templates.TemplateType, SessionNames.SessionType

FROM (SessionNames LEFT JOIN Templates ON SessionNames.Template = Templates.TemplateID) INNER JOIN (SessionsTN3270 LEFT JOIN LUs ON SessionsTN3270.SessionID = LUs.SessionID) ON SessionNames.SessionNameID = SessionsTN3270.SessionNameID WHERE UserNameID = 3978 ORDER BY Templates.TemplateType, SessionNames.SessionType;

go
```

From this SQL tracing I found I can replicate the same order from SQL server using the query, starting like this:

```
SELECT "dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."SessionID" ,"dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."SessionID","dbo"."SessionNames"."SessionType" ,"dbo"."SessionNames"."SessionNameID","dbo"."Templates"."TemplateType" ,"dbo"."Templates"."TemplateID" FROM "dbo"."SessionsTN3270", "dbo"."SessionNames" LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."Templates" ON ("dbo"."SessionNames"."Template" = "dbo"."Templates"."TemplateID" ) 
 WHERE (("dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."UserNameID" = 3978 ) AND ("dbo"."SessionNames"."SessionNameID" = "dbo"."SessionsTN3270"."SessionNameID" ) )
```

Comment: If your order by columns don't specify unique values, then the order within the same values is essentially random. There's no realistic way to replicate it from one DBMS to another. In fact, if you rebuild indexes on SQL Server, or compress an Access database, the order may well change.

Comment: If you are moving/upgrading an application to use SQL server, why would you want to duplicate the flaw sorting order provided by Access.  I would think one would want to correct sorting whatever that may be.

Comment: The data is coming from the same SQL server. The Access application is not storing any data in the database, it is retrieving it using same ODBC connection string, from the SQL server. I agree the sort order is "random" in sense  it is "unspecified" The reason the sort order is important because the app was written in such a s**t way that it relied on the order stuff comes back. If I can't fix it, I've got to fix a whole lot of other sections of code. Which is my backup plan...but frankly the less time I spend in spaghetti code land the better.

Comment: sessionstn3270.sessionid should be in your ORDER BY. It should be in that order 100% of the time. If not, then you have to figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

The solution was to use ExpressProfiler (http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/) If you have full SQL, use SQL Profile included with SQL. By tracing queries with ExpressProfiler I was able to match the query that ACCESS used, as it ACCESS modifies the SQL query before sent to SQL server, then I can get results in same order. The full details I put in this blog post: http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/case-of-the-sql-vs-access-sort-order/